# Javascript - Redirect to homepage after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form:

```
  <form name="orderform" onsubmit="submitForm()">
 HTML HERE
.
.
.
<button type="submit" name="submitbutton"   id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
```

and the functions:

```
function submitForm()
{
 submitted = true;
 goHome(submitted);
}
```

and

```
function goHome(submitted)
{
  if(redirect == submitted)
{
  alert("form submitted");
  document.location.href = "index.html";
}
}
```

I'm trying to make my page display an alert message and then redirect to index.html after the form is submitted but i can't seem to get it right in any way. 
I've tried using `onClick` at submit button or submitting the form purely with Javascript (`document["orderform].submit();` and `document.getElementById("orderform");`) but that did'nt work.

My guess was that these functions were being executed at the same time as the submission, leading the submission to execute over them. So, I added `setTimeout` for `function goHome();` to be executed or tried `window.onload = goHome();` but nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions?

PS: I'm not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the standard HTML FORM submit process, the old page is destroyed and a new page is loaded.

There are two solutions:

- The best way: Have whatever page you submit your form to issue a HTTP redirect in its header.
- The much less desirable way: Submit the form via Ajax and then do a JavaScript re-direct upon success.

Comment: I wouldn't know how that works and google doesn't seem to give me anything back. Besides, I'm at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Set the appropriate part of the head of the html file to include

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="3;url=index.html"> <!-- 3 seconds to reload here -->
```

inside your goHome function.